# How to purchase an OST?

Tags: music, merchandise

Can anyone point me in the direction of a legal online seller of OSTs? There are a few anime and OVAs that I want to own but I have no idea where to search?

A link or two would be upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is of course [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_n_6?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A42%2Ck%3AAnime+soundtracks&keywords=Anime+soundtracks&ie=UTF8&qid=1480961577&rnid=2941120011)  That links to a soundtracks search that brings up Anime OSTs............and games for some reason.

There is [cdJapan](http://www.cdjapan.co.jp/)

Those are the ones I have used.

Comment: FWIW amazon.co.jp has a better selection than amazon.com, and most of their CDs ship internationally.

Answer (score 2):

There are several soundtracks, or in some cases just singles, on iTunes, although of course availability will depend on region. Sometimes it can help to search for either an artist or a song title, and see what albums show up, but you have to be careful because for every actual version of an anisong, there are about twenty covers of varying quality and style (including entire albums where as far as I can tell they've taken a MIDI version of the songs and run it through a synthesiser to make it sound like church bells, for reasons that completely escape me).

You'll get the best results if you're able to switch to the Japanese iTunes store, although there may be some hoops to jump through to make that work properly (for example, you can only buy something from a new region if you have no iTunes credit in your usual region). And, of course, everything's in Japanese - if you're not a speaker yourself, use Wikipedia or ANN or a similar site to find the Japanese name of the show you're looking for, and copy it into the search bar.

Comment: Anisong.......is that a term now?  If so.......I sigh immensely

Comment: I just romanised the Japanese word because I was feeling lazy at the time.